# Aws lambda return promise

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-lambda

I am working with aws lamda and creating a function returning a promise from it and then consuming it in my client function in node. Due to some reason it is returning Promise and i am not able to figure out what is wrong here. Here is the following code snippet : -

Lamda Function

```
function paymentConfirmationMessage() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("I came from lamda");
        }, 20000);
    });
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let calculationResult = await paymentConfirmationMessage();
    return calculationResult;
}
```

In node client : -

```
const https = require("https");
const url = "SomeLamdaurl.com/get";

function getData(url) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        https.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
            resolve(body);
        });
    });
}
 async function test(){
    var body = await getData(url);
    if (body) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log('obj', obj);
    }
    else {
    }
 }
test();
```

Additionally when i am making call from api gateway setup in lamda i am getting the desired response.

Any lead will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: In your "https.get" call, you are not handling errors. That might hide errors. Regarding why it is returning a Promise, I might have misunderstood your question, but you are wrapping it in Promises, so it is expected to get a Promise.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but are you invoking the lambda via http directly (as your url variable suggests)? Then it should be a POST request (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html). To troubleshoot you can also invoke the lambda via the management console or via CLI and check if the result matches what you expect.